# How to Extract Color Given Word or Sentence

Tags: python, machine-learning, nltk, data-science

I am in the middle of trying to cleanup several hundred thousand lines of data that is managed by users inputting data into a field. There has been no re-cleaning of the data after input masks were recently set.

Now I am trying to hypothesize given a word(Color) or sentence(may or may not have a Color in it) passed into a function and return its best Color guess.

Is there a library that currently does this that I am not aware of?

**Example**

**Input:**
INT SATIN BASE

**Output:**
SATIN

**Input:**
Light Red

**Output:**
Red

**Input:**
Latching Box - White

**Output:**
White

Comment: Input/output examples?

Comment: Just updated the original post

Answer (score 3):

You can use python `colour` package to check where input keyword is color or not. To install, use `pip install colour`

```
>>> from colour import Color
>>> s = 'Light Red'
>>> _color = [i for i in s.split(' ') if check_color(i)]
['Red']
```

Here is the custom function:

```
def check_color(color):
    try:
        Color(color)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False
```

Answer (score 1):

Obtain a list of common color names (e.g. from https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_colors) and collect them in a list.

Then, using the list of color names and the input string, search for any color name which exists within the input string.

```
color_names = [..., "Satin", ...]
input_str = "INT SATIN BASE"
found_colors = [color for color in color_names if color.lower() in input_str.lower()]
```

I did rudimentary input cleaning via `.lower()` in an effort to increase the chance of a string like `SATIN` matching `Satin`, however additional data cleaning may be required if the input string could potentially contain characters which are unwanted.